# Excel VBA looping through multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

VBA beginner here, I've got a little problem with program I'm working on.

I need to copy data from last cell in column B from first worksheet and paste it into column A in another worksheet xws, and repeate this operation for five other worksheets with data.

Here's the code, it doesn't work the way it should:

```
Sub exercise()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    'Finding last row in column B
    Set rng = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Don't copy data from xws worksheet
        If ws.Name <> "xws" Then
            'Storing first copied data in A1
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("xws").[A1]) Then
                rng.Copy Sheets("xws").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            'Storing next copied data below previously filled cell
            Else
                rng.Copy Sheets("xws").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

There is a problem with ws. referring, but whenever I put it before rng in if statements or before range (set rng = ...) I get errors.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: When I start macro from active worksheet, I get the same information copied into six cells (A1:A6) in workshet xws, only from active worksheet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be declaring `rng` for each `ws` inside the loop, like:

```
Sub exercise()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Finding last row in column B
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp) '<~~ Moved inside the loop
        'Don't copy data from xws worksheet
        If ws.Name <> "xws" Then
            'Storing first copied data in A1
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("xws").[A1]) Then
                rng.Copy Sheets("xws").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            'Storing next copied data below previously filled cell
            Else
                rng.Copy Sheets("xws").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

As your code is now, `rng` will be pointing to the `ActiveSheet` at the time you run the macro, and your code will then copy the same cell on each iteration of the code.