# excel VBA script VLOOKUP other file with unknown worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Im trying to create a VBA script with a VLOOKUP to another workbook. The name of the 2nd workbook is always Stock.xls. The data in Stock.xls is always in the **first worksheet**, but the name of this sheet is different every day. It can be ARTLIST1, ARTLIST2, ARTLIST(3), ARTLIST-4 etc... but always starts with ARTLIST.
How can I tell the VBA script just to use the first sheet, or the sheet always contains the word ARTLIST (e.g. ARTLIST*)

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(C[-36],'[Stock.xls]ARTLIST1'!R1:R65536,13,0)"
Selection.Copy
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Richard

Comment: Have you looked for anything? Plenty of examples on this site. [Here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25953980/4243498)

Comment: Did you try searching? The INDIRECT() function does pretty much exactly this... You can use INDIRECT(A1) where A1 contains the sheet name you are looking for.

Comment: With INDIRECT i need to place the name of the worksheet in A1, correct? I need something full automatic.. where I do not need to fill in anything to select the first sheet. Ideally, instead of ARTLIST1 in my code above, it would state Worksheet(1) or  ARTLIST*.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference it by index and the get the name. Then you the name variable in the building of the formula.

```
Dim wsName as string
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Application.Worksheets(1)
wsName = ws.Name

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-36],'[Stock.xls]" & wsName & "'!R1:R65536,13,0)"
Selection.Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet with index of 1 to get the first sheet:

```
For each ws in worksheetsFor Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Index = 1 Then
      'Do code, this is the first worksheet
  End If
Next ws
```