# How to add cells across an unknown number of multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-docs, openoffice-calc

In a spreadsheet, Sheet0 is the first and farthest left sheet in a series of tabs and is a summary of all worksheets to its right. Adding cells from multiple sheets is easy enough when the sheets are known, but is it possible to add, for example, cell A5 across all sheets that are not Sheet0?

We have multiple contributors to the workbook, each will input their own page based on their sales results, if any, so we'll never know the number of sheets in a given period.

We're entering data into Google Docs spreadsheets, but the answer doesn't have to be product specific. Excel, Open Office, Google Docs, any would be fine.

Comment: In Excel, `For each worksheet in activeworkbook.worksheets // If worksheet.Name <> "Sheet0" Then`... What have you tried? This is a pretty straightforward and common request, you should be able to find ample documentation here on SO and via general internet searches

Comment: if you type 'adding cells from unknown number of multiple worksheets' this 60 min old post is one of the top listings. Obviously I tried researching a topic about which I know nothing about and don't have enough understanding to even know how to best formulate a search; and when that fell through I tried asking a community of knowledgeable people. You all but answered the question, it seems, in the comment. And if it's so straightforward and you have all these resources to reference, why would you not just put a helpful answer?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're more than willing to help but ask that you show some effort on your side too as this isn't a "code for me" site but rather "help me with my code". If you've tried something, please update your post with the relevant code.  As mentioned, you should be able to find many ways to do this. [Here's one SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953916/excel-vba-looping-through-multiple-worksheets). What have you searched for? Try looking through [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+loop+through+worksheets)

Answer (score 0):

Won't work in OpenOffice and certainly not in Google Docs (nor Sheets) but might work in Excel:

Add a sheet at the end (right) and use that as the end of the sheet range of 3D formulae that start with the sheet next to `Sheet0`. Hide the sheet on the extreme right  and hopefully any added sheets will be in the visible part and hence automatically included in the 3D range.