# Format Variable Number Of Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I used the Microsoft Excel 2016 macro recorder to come with the code below. It works great on a single worksheet. I get a workbook once a month with a different number of worksheets. I would like to automate this task by using Excel VBA. Is there an easy way to loop through each worksheet applying the following formats? The names of each of the tabs are always different.

...

```
   Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Passed", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Failed", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Error", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Passed", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Failed", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Error", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Passed"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Failed"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Error"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Defects"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Manufacturing Days"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Yield"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Percent Defects"
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total " & Chr(10) & "Defects"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Manufacturing" & Chr(10) & " Days"
    Range("A7").Select
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:A").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

...

Comment: This will give you a good start on avoiding using selections (use qualified objects instead) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Then read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953916/excel-vba-looping-through-multiple-worksheets

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. You have to follow this simple steps:

1. Wrap your formatting code into a `Sub`, like this:

   ```
   Sub FormatSingleSheet()
       Cells.Select
       Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Passed", _
           TextOperator:=xlContains
       Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

       With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
           .Bold = True
           .Italic = False
           .Color = -16711681
           .TintAndShade = 0
       End With

       '[...] Rest of the code [...]
   End Sub
   ```
2. Create a `Sub` that calls the previous one for each of your `Worksheet`:

   ```
   Sub FormatAllSheets()
       Dim index As Integer, WS_Count As Integer
       WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

       For index = 1 To WS_Count
           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(index).Activate
           Call FormatSingleSheet
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

This will apply your formatting to all your `Sheets`.

> **Note**: I've tested this code on my Workbook and it works.

Hope this helps.